# String was not recognised as valid datetime for arabic language

Tags: c#, datetime, uwp, cultureinfo

I'm using below code for convert string to datetime(with slected language). It works well for all other language except Arabic. When passing ar as CultureInfo it throws an error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". What is the reason of it?

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ar"); //works well for en,de,fr,hi,ru
string mDate = "2018-07-15 17:00";
DateTime userTime = Convert.ToDateTime(mDate,ci);
```

Comment: not all country can show time.

Comment: @lindexi: What do you mean by that?

Comment: It's worth nothing that if the time is specified as `2018-07-15T17:00`, this works even if the culture is `AR`, because that format is universally treated as ISO 8601. Per Jon's answer, though, if you know your string is ISO (or some other exact format), you should parse it accordingly, not leave it up to the culture.

Comment: @JeroenMostert   yes , it works when changing to 2018-07-15T17:00. But both are different right?  mDate is coming from a webservice. I have no right to change it's format . Is there any other way? it works for all languages in android.

Answer (score 7):

The main problem is that the "ar" culture has a different default calendar system - it's trying to parse that as a date in the Um Al Qura calendar. If you print `ci.DateTimeFormat.Calendar` it will show `System.Globalization.UmAlQuraCalendar`, whereas the value you've shown is presumably in the Gregorian calendar system. So even if the value could be parsed, it wouldn't represent the value you'd expect it to.

There's a secondary problem that you're using the default formats supported by the "ar" culture - that's not a good idea unless you know that the value was definitely provided as a human readable value for that specific culture.

Given that the value is in ISO-8601 format, it looks like it's actually intended to be machine readable rather than human readable - so I'd suggest parsing using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (and ideally using `DateTime.ParseExact` rather than `Convert.ToDateTime`). You can then decide whether you want to *display* the value to the user in their calendar system or not.

Comment: I would even go a step further and say that 99 out of 100 times, when people use `Convert.ToDateTime` they really should use `TryParseExact`...

Comment: DateTime userTime = DateTime.ParseExact(mDate, "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt", ci); shows same error

Comment: @nsds Does `2018-07-15 17:00` look like `dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt` format to you?

Comment: @nsds: `02/11/39 05:00:00 م` parses just fine -- if you insist on using the `ar` culture for parsing, use the `ar` format.

Comment: it shows same error when tried with 
                   DateTime userTime=  DateTime.ParseExact(mDate, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @nsds: That's because you should be using `HH` instead of `hh` - 17 is valid as a 24-hour value, but not as a 12-hour value.

Comment: @JonSkeet    DateTime userTime = DateTime.ParseExact( "2018-06-14 18:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  when using this code, output get as {30/09/39 06:00:00 م}

Comment: @JonSkeet and when using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture wll not convert the time to selected language.

Comment: @nsds: A `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a language or a format, or even a calendar system. It's always in the Gregorian calendar. You need to be really clear about that. You use one format/culture/calendar to parse, then you can choose a different one to format the value back to a string. It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve - what you *expect* the result to be.